# Android Studio and OpenCV 'Compilation Error', 'Cannot resolve symbol styleable'

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv

I'm using android studio version 3.3 and openCV version 4.0.1

After setting up openCV in android studio, when I run the app to check if the openCV loaded successfully, an error occurred saying 'Compilation Failed'. I checked the problem and I saw an error 'Cannot resolve symbol 'styleable'.

I already tried cleaning and rebuilding project. I also updated the sdk version of the gradle scripts.

This is my app gradle script:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.homesafe.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', 'src/main/jniLibs/'] } }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':openCVLibrary401')
}
```

this is my openCV gradle scripts:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    //buildToolsVersion "x.y.z" // not needed since com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['../../jni']
            java.srcDirs = ['src']  // TODO Use original files instead of copied into build directory
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['/build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/java/android_sdk/android_gradle_lib/res']
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVItG.png)

i don't know what's the problem here. any help? thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

You need to replace the following line:

```
res.srcDirs = ['/build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/java/android_sdk/android_gradle_lib/res']
```

with this:

```
res.srcDirs = ['res']
```